# Switched from singleton to application object, still getting null pointer exceptions

Tags: java, android

I switched from a singleton to an application object to store application data because as I understood it, there was a much better chance of my cached data surviving in an application object, than in a regular singleton.

I am still having issues however.  If I switch to several other apps, and come back to my app, the call to load my event after i've loaded `getApplication()` is throwing an null pointer exception.

What I find even more bizarre, is that the bundle from my original intent, is still active and has survived the application switching.

How can I keep data, which doesn't necessarily need to be persisted in a permanent way (if the entire application were killed, and reloaded, it would just pull it down from the webservice and start fresh, this is why I thought switching to an application object would be ok )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to persist data relating to when your application is put into the background by the user, and then brought back?

Perhaps overriding the methods onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, and storing and recovering from a bundle is what you are looking for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

You may then want to define a Parcelable interface

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

on the classes you wish to store.

Alternatively You may also use the shared preferences api.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: I have considered SaveInstanceState as well as sharedpreferences as I am already storing some things there (like a facebook token) however I am dealing with an ArrayList of HashMaps which is somewhat large, while it can be done, its not very simple to put it into a bundle, or sharedpreferences (I know that newer sdk versions allow storage of sets, but I am targeting back to level 8).  If there is an easy way to convert to either of those, I would love to hear it, I am pretty new to Java.

Comment: It depends a bit on how large is "quite large", but sometimes for storing square pins in round holes I will marshal out to XML or JSON and store as a string value. JSON being slightly smaller you can use something like Jackson which works under Android http://jackson.codehaus.org/. I suspect that ArrayList of HashMaps might already be supported by Jackson.

Comment: That looks like an awesome library, thank you for that!  One of the things I am not understanding is this: by switching to an application object, isn't it supposed to be there for the life of my application?  My app recovers fine from a "force stop", but when moved to the background (and lots of other apps opened) then reopened, it fails, (it works if moved to the background and reopened with only 1 or 2 apps opened in between)

Comment: Tom - perhaps posting a piece of your source code might help with this specific problem.